# html5 offline storage prepared db

Tags: html, offline

I'm trying to write an iphone web app displaying info from a small ish database while offline. Is it possible to prepare a db and download that rather than downloading the data in some other format and creating it on first use?

if i have to create db, what would be a good format (is there eg compressed xml?) to send data?

is there a maximum storage limit for local dbs?

Answer (score 3):

You could either store it as a large chunk of XML, using HTML 5 Storage, or as a database using Web Database Storage - plain storage is better suported by web browsers (Latest Firefox only seems to suppor the former, for instance).

Secondly, there is no size limit defined in the HTML 5 standard - it simply states:

> User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage
>   areas.

For more information, have a look at the [HTML 5 Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/), or at these [demos](http://html5demos.com/).

Answer (score 1):

More information on html5 can be found at [html5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)